# Old Postgresql Volume Mounted with Container but not showing the Databases

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

I have deleted the old postgresql container having 4 databases in it. Those 4 databases were kept persisted in volume. Later I made another container and mounted the previous old postgresql volume (having 4 databases) with this new container of postgresql, The volume was successfully mounted but when i `exec`  that container and opened the `psql` shell inside this new container and typed `\l` it is not showing the previous 4 databases stored in old volume. I have performed the following steps to make the new container and mount with new volume:

1. Created the new Container

   ```
   sudo docker run --name postgresql-container -p 5432:5432 -e
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somePassword -d postgres
   ```
2. postgresql old volume (having 4 databases) attached with new
   container

   ```
   sudo docker container run -itd -v
   bf6c9d65bce874795c1b3af1071008a6115b3f63400efb8af655bb9a1ae0f08a:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   postgres
   ```

In step 2 the volume was successfully attached with container, i have inspected the container with following command:

```
sudo docker container inspect
fb1f0924f127c6ae3aa49d2c4ee1331697cc5a4930d6c7eae9944defd6c6ef5b
```

You can see the volume is correctly mounted in below json format

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "c792a1d5214bcb2ef57eab1b07b41871a0fdf0159d0efa545b0c0e71dee7ba58",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/c792a1d5214bcb2ef57eab1b07b41871a0fdf0159d0efa545b0c0e71dee7ba58/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

When i run this new container with the following and inspect the database it does not show the previous stored databases in volumes:

```
sudo docker exec -it
fb1f0924f127c6ae3aa49d2c4ee1331697cc5a4930d6c7eae9944defd6c6ef5b bash
```

where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Your command says you map the volume to `/var/lab/postgresql` but your inspect says that it's mapped to `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. Please fix your post to make it accurate.

Comment: Thank you, i had edited the question, but still looking for the solution, my problem not resolved yet

Comment: It still says 'lab' instead of 'lib' in the command. The best way is to use copy/paste a lot when you post :)

Comment: improved the question